# Summability in an Orthogonal Family of Vectors for Uncountable Index Sets

Tags: summation, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

**Background:** I'm studying the properties of summability within orthogonal (possibly uncountable) families of vectors and have come across the following theorem (Theorem 8.2 of *"Introduction to Hilbert Space and the Theory of Spectral Multiplicity"* by P. R. Halmos).

**Theorem:**
An orthogonal family of vectors $\left\{ x_{j} \right\}$ is summable if and only if the family $\left\{ \| x_{j} \|^{2} \right \}$ of positive numbers is summable; this condition may also be expressed by writing $\Sigma_j\left\|x_j\right\|^2<\infty$. If $x=\Sigma_j x_j$, then $\|x\|^2=\Sigma_j\left\|x_j\right\|^2$.

**Proof:**
$\ldots$

The second assertion of the theorem is a consequence of the relations
$$
\|x\|^{2}
=
\langle x, x\rangle 
=
\left\langle \Sigma_j x_{j}, x \right \rangle
=
\Sigma_{j} \left \langle x_{j}, x \right \rangle
=
 \Sigma_{j} \left\langle x_{j}, \Sigma_k x_{k}\right \rangle
 =
 \Sigma_j \Sigma_k \left\langle x_{j}, x_{k}\right\rangle
=
\Sigma_j \left\langle x_{j}, x_{j} \right\rangle
=
\Sigma_j \| x_{j} \|^{2} .
$$
(The second to last step in this chain of equations depends on the obvious fact that if all but one of the terms of a family of vectors, or, in particular, of complex numbers, are zero, then that family is summable and its sum is the exceptional term.)

**Question:** Am I right that the author implicitly makes use of the fact that the convergence of an uncountable sum implies that at most countable many elements are non-zero? Hence the above sums are all over countable index sets?

To be more explicit if $J=\mathbb{N}$ the chain of equations follows by exploiting linearity and continuity of the inner product. F.e. in that case, the second "$ = $" involves the following steps which are usually hidden:
$$
\left \langle x, x \right \rangle
=
\left \langle \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}x_{j}, x \right \rangle
=
\left \langle \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{j=1}^{n}x_{j}, x\right \rangle
=
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left \langle  \sum_{j=1}^{n}x_{j}, x \right \rangle
=
\lim_{n \to \infty}   \sum_{j=1}^{n} \left \langle x_{j}, x \right \rangle
=
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \left \langle x_{j}, x \right \rangle
$$

---

**Definition:**
A family $\{x_{j}\}$ of vectors will be called **summable** with **sum** $x$ in symbols $\sum_{j}x_{j} = x$, if for every positive number $\epsilon$ there exists a finite set $J_{0}$ of indices such that $\| x - \sum_{j \in J}x_{j} \| < \epsilon$ whenever $J$ is a finite set of indices containing $J_{0}$.

Comment: what is your definition for summability?

Comment: This (the fact that the convergence of an uncountable sum implies that at most countable many elements are non-zero) is useless here. You can do the same steps with summable families.

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace I've added the definition.

Comment: @AnneBauval How? My first idea would be to use that by summability we have for  $\epsilon > 0$ a $J_{0}$ with $\| \left\langle \Sigma_{j \in J} x_{j}, x \right\rangle
-
\Sigma_{j \in J} \left \langle x_{j}, x \right \rangle
 \| < \epsilon$ for every finite $J$ with $J_{0} \subset J$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the convergence of an uncountable sum implies that at most countable many elements are non-zero is useless here. You can do the same steps with summable families, as follows.

Let us assume $\sum_jx_j=x$ and prove that $\|x\|^2=\sum_j\left\|x_j\right\|^2.$

By hypothesis, for every positive number $\epsilon$, there exists a finite set $J_0$ of indices such that $\| x - \sum_{j \in J}x_j\| < \epsilon$ whenever $J$ is a finite set of indices containing $J_0$.

For $\epsilon,J$ as above, and $y:=\sum_{j \in J}x_j$, we have
$$\begin{align}\|x\|^2&=\langle x,x-y\rangle+\langle x,y\rangle\\
&=\langle x,x-y\rangle+\langle x-y,y\rangle+\|y\|^2.\end{align}$$
By Cauchy-Schwarz and triangular inequalities,
$$\left|\langle x,x-y\rangle+\langle x-y,y\rangle\right|\le\epsilon(\|x\|+\|y\|)\le\epsilon(2\|x\|+\epsilon).$$
Moreover, since the $x_j$'s are pairwise orthogonal, $\|y\|^2=\sum_{j\in J}\|x_j\|^2.$

We thus proved that $\forall\epsilon>0,\exists J_0$ finite, $\forall J$ finite $\supset J_0,$
$$\left|\|x\|^2-\sum_{j\in J}\|x_j\|^2\right|\le\epsilon(2\|x\|+\epsilon).$$

To conclude, it suffices to notice that $\forall\eta>0,\exists\epsilon>0,\epsilon(2\|x\|+\epsilon)<\eta$, i.e. $\epsilon\in\left(0,-\|x\|+\sqrt{\|x\|^2+\eta}\right).$

Comment: Thanks. Maybe you could add how you derived $\|x\|^{2}=\langle x, x-y \rangle+\langle x-y, y \rangle+\|y\|^{2}$. Am I right that you sued this steps: $\|x\|^{2}
=
\langle x,x \rangle
=
\langle x, x \pm y \rangle
=
\langle x,x-y \rangle+\langle x , y\rangle
=
\langle x,x-y \rangle+\langle x \pm y , y\rangle
=
\langle x,x-y \rangle+\langle x - y , y\rangle+\langle y, y \rangle
$

Comment: One last question. Your proof shows that $\|x\|^2=\sum_{j}\|x_{j}\|^{2}$ using the definition of summability. This doesn't explain how the proof given by the author works, especially why f.e. $\langle \sum_{j} x_{j}, x \rangle= \sum_{j} \langle x_{j}, x \rangle$ holds.

Comment: My proof is the same as the author's, only written differently. His first step $\langle \sum_{j} x_{j}, x \rangle= \sum_{j} \langle x_{j}, x \rangle$ corresponds to my $\|x\|^2=\langle x,x-y\rangle+\langle x,y\rangle$ and $|\langle x,x-y\rangle|\le\epsilon\|x\|.$